# Are there and constraints on the Mode functions for the Dirac equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization

I have some doubts about the following issue: conventionally, one expands the Dirac field operator in mode functions of positive/negative energy in order to introduce creation/annihilation operators. Following Peskin & Schroeder's conventions:
$$
\hat{\psi}(x)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_\bf{p}}}\sum_s\left(\hat{a}_p^s u^s(p)e^{-ip\cdot x}+\hat{b}_p^{s\dagger}v^s(p)e^{ip\cdot x}\right),
$$

where $u^s(p)$ and $v^s(p)$ satisfy certain orthonormality conditions.
This, to my knowledge, is interpreted as $\hat{a}^s_p$ destroying a particle of state $u^s(p)e^{-i p\cdot x}$ and $\hat{b}^{s\dagger}_p$ destroying a particle of state $v^s(p)e^{i p\cdot x}$, i.e. plane waves.
Nonetheless, if one were to reexpress this field operator $\hat{\psi}$ in other basis of mode functions (not plane waves), using for example new mode functios satisfying orthonormality (I will denote them by $A(p,\,x)$ and $B(p,\,x)$), one would have
$$
\hat{\psi}(x)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_\bf{p}}}\sum_s\left(\hat{\tilde{a}}_p^s A(p,\,x)+\hat{\tilde{b}}_p^{s\dagger}B(p,\,x)\right),
$$

where the new operators $\hat{\tilde{a}}^s_p$ and $\hat{\tilde{b}}^{s\dagger}_p$ are related to the old ones $\hat{{a}}^s_p$ and $\hat{{b}}^{s\dagger}_p$ by a Bogoliubov transformation. I understand that the only change would be that the new operators $\hat{\tilde{a}}^s_p$ and $\hat{\tilde{b}}^{s\dagger}_p$$a_p$ are to be interpreted as creating/destroying particles on the state $A(p,\,x)$/$B(p,\,x)$, respectively.

My question is: can this "change of basis" **always** be done, as long as the mode functions are orthonormal, or must the mode functions obey some constraints?

Comment: Orthonormal and *complete* will work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!